# How to send email after registration in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using the auth system that comes with laravel 5 and would like to send notification email after registration. I tried adding a method that sends email(and it works I tested) in postReigster method of AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsrers.php but it doesn't work.

Please help

The code I tried adding in registrar create and authandregister postRegister

```
   $email = EmailTemplate::all()->first();
        Mail::raw($email->topic, function($message) use ($data, $email)
        {

            $message->from($email->sender, $email->sender);

            $message->to($data->email);
        });
```

Comment: what have you done so far ? please share the code.

Comment: I used the Mail::raw() method to test if postRegister is fired but it doesn't. All I need is where to put the method

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send mail after Laravel 5 default registration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173028/how-to-send-mail-after-laravel-5-default-registration)

Answer (score 0):

You must add your code in this file:

/app/Services/Registrar.php

to this function before return you must add something like:

```
public function create(array $data)
{

 your_mail_function($data['email'], 'towhom', 'subject' );

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Why can't I add it in postRegister?

Comment: @zarcel well i'm not sure what have you done exactly. an example code could help.

Comment: I added the code. Ok i have fixed it - still don't understand why it didn't fail and show errors when I passed null as receiver email address.