# How to remove the default mail sending after registration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

We got the following error message after successful registration in laravel 5.5.

```
{ "message": "Address in mailbox given [1593698521] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.", "exception": "Swift_RfcComplianceException", "file": "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Mime\\Headers\\MailboxHeader.php", "line": 354, "trace": [ { "file": "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Mime\\Headers\\MailboxHeader.php", "line": 271, "function": "assertValidAddress", "class": "Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader", "type": "->" }
```

We dont need to mail sending after registration. How to disable mail sending in laravel. We couldn't find the default swift mail sending coding. Please tell me how to disable the mail sending option.

Comment: Not flagging for duplicate, since it strictly isn't. But all the info  you need is right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173028/how-to-send-mail-after-laravel-5-default-registration

Comment: share code from where you register user `User::create(` ?

Comment: protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user=  User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'role' => "user",
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'email2' => $data['email2'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
             'confirmed' => true,
            'valid' => true,
        ]);

        

         return $user;
    }

Comment: Laravel does not send the email at the time of registration. Have you changed the code?

Comment: agreed if you just used php artisan make:auth emails shouldnt be sent, have you manually created an event that sents emails after user row is updated?

Answer (score 0):

I took registration and everything from laravel as from auth command:

- Remove `implements MustVerifyEmail` from `class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail` in `app\User.php` (This won't send an email after registration)

  (If u dont want to send verification mail, then just do the above and done).

If you wanted to send registration mail after some event in my site but that too with default laravel mail sender, so for that you need to do the following:

- change the `show()` method in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails.php`

  ```
  public function show(Request $request)
  {
      return $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()
          ? redirect($this->redirectPath())
          : $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
  }
  ```
- And on any controller, you can set `return redirect('/email/verify');` line to send verification email, if you want
  or invoke sending a mail with `'/email/verify'`
  as this will call the same email verification but whenever you want, rather than after user registration.